# Full documentation on formatting?

Tags: discussion, support, formatting, stackexchange

> Is there any documentation which lists all formatting options on SE sites, such as this one `>!`, as I couldn't find anywhere that even mentioned this one?

Comment: cool effect =) like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's [right there](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#spoilers) with the [other formatting help.](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help)

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice it there! :D

Answer (score 1):

[Learn to search better.](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#spoilers)

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice it there! :D